# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type int and 'Model'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I know this error is on here a few times but I cannot find a solution to my particular problem.

I have a table with a `foreach loop` which populates the table data as you can see below, also this table has an expand/close capability, within this i want to display all the groups in there relevant sections. The Error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'GroupSection'` is appearing in the line:

`if (item.SectionID == item.GroupSectionID)`

I want to make sure that the groups details can only appear if its GroupSectionID is the same as the SectionID in that particular loop

**Table**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <!-- Render the table headers. -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1">+</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Section ID</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Section Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Render the details of each employee. -->
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1">+</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.SectionID)</td>
                <td class="col-md-3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.SectionName)</td>
            </tr>

            if (item.SectionID == item.GroupSectionID)
            {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1" colspan="3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GroupID)</td>
                <td class="col-md-2" colspan="3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GroupName)</td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**Model**

```
public class SectionDetail
{
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public GroupDetail GroupSectionID { get; set; }

}

public class GroupDetail
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupDescription { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int GroupSectionID { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance and I am relatively new to Stack so if you need and more information etc. please let me know

Comment: I suspect it needs to be `if (item.SectionID == item.GroupSectionID.GroupID)` or maybe `.. == item,GroupSectionID.GroupSectionID)` But why do you have 3 properties in your model which are typeof `GroupDetail`? And with names that names that don't appear to have any relationship to what they actual represent? (very strange)

Comment: Basically each section is made up of various groups so section x has groups y and z, section t has groups a, b and l etc..

Comment: So I retrieve the Details about the Group and details about the Section from separate tables in a database with the SectionID as the Primary Key, so i would like to use this primary key (SectionID and GroupSectionID) to decide which child (group) elements each parent (section) element will contain

Comment: Then your properties should be named appropriately, (say) `GroupX`, `GroupY`, etc  - but still it does not make sense - which one of those properties are you wanting to compare the ID to?. And unless each section has exactly the same number of groups (say 3), then your property should be `IEnumerable<GroupDetail> Groups` - i.e. one property containing a collection of the groups associated with the section.

Comment: After debugging the problem is that in the `foreach` the GroupSectionID is returning null everytime but when i checked in the Controller the GroupDetail Model is being populated

Comment: You should start by naming you property `public GroupDetail Group { get; set; }` so at least it makes sense.

Comment: As for your current problem, you need to ask a new question and show your controller code where you populate your collection of `SectionDetail` objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84078/discussion-between-hjardine-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing an `int` to the complex type `GroupDetail`.

```
if (item.SectionID == item.GroupSectionID.GroupSectionID)
```

I think you're looking for the `GroupSectionID` property inside of the `GroupDetail` class.

**To prevent future confusion:**

I suggest removing the `ID` suffix from properties that are references to other classes. This way you won't mistake it for an `int` again :)

Comment: Thank you very much! i thought it would be simple :) will mark as correct after 10 minutes @NielsFilter

Comment: I just ran it and got this error back `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @hjardine, That would be because property `GroupSectionID` is null (you have not initialized it (but review my comment to your question above - why do you have 3 properties which are typeof `GroupDetail`? - your model just does not make any sense as it is

Comment: @hjardine, Stephen Muecke's right. Either make sure `item.GroupSectionID` is initialized or change your `if` to ignore html if it's null: `if (item.GroupSectionID != null && item.SectionID == item.GroupSectionID.GroupSectionID)`

Comment: I have edited the code so that it only contains one now, i have put more detail in response to you previous comment

Comment: I marked this a Correct as it answered my original problem, but if you have any idea why it is returning null it would be appreciated

Comment: @hjardine, Debug and have a look at your Model before it's sent to your view. It might be valid to have `null` value? Will be good to change the `if` to include a null check: `if (item.GroupSectionID != null && item.SectionID == item.GroupSectionID.GroupSectionID)`

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to ask the compiler to compare between two different types.

item.SectionID is a `int type`, while `item.GroupSectionID` is a `class type`.

change your comparison to represent what you actually trying to compare, something similar to:

```
if (item.SectionID == item.GroupSectionID.GroupSectionID)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but as Niels was first to answer i will give him the correct answer

Comment: I just ran it and got this error back `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @hjardine, Than you should check why `GroupSectionID` is null and fix it accordingly.